# DocuSign send Evenlope as draft to multiple recipients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, docusignapi

Currently I'm sending an envelope with a pdf document to multiple recipients but only the first one receives it(which is incidentally the impersonated user).
The recipient list is as follows:

```
recipients = DocuSign_eSign::Recipients.new(
      'carbonCopies' => [cc1, candidate], 
      'signers' => [signer4],
      'agents' => [signer1],
      'editors' => [signer3],
      'witnesses' => [signer5])


    envelope_definition.recipients = recipients
    # Request that the envelope be sent by setting status to "sent".
    # To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set status to "created"
    envelope_definition.status = 'created'
    envelope_definition
```

Do I need bulk sending? Can I push the envelope to everyones Draft inboxes?

Comment: When you create an envelope in `created` status, it won't be delivered to the recipients.  Only after the status is `sent` is when the recipients receive the envelope.

Answer (score 1):

An envelope in `created` (draft) status is not sent to anyone.

Instead, it is waiting until its status is changed to `sent`.

A draft envelope is only available to the creator (the sender).

You may wish to create a new question in StackOverflow where you detail your use case: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I wanted to have it as draft for every potential recipient in the list. But I think it is not possible to do so.

Comment: Sorry, recipients can't see an envelope until it is sent.